# Make search_fields for integer value

Tags: python, django

I made models like this and it has the IntegerField.

```
class Corpus(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(null=False)
    manual = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    issues = models.ManyToManyField(Issue,blank=True,null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return  self.text
```

And I set, "search_fields' admin class.

I expected pull down menu for `manual` however there is only one text box on the page.

```
class CorpusAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['text','manual']
    search_fields = ['text','manual']
    list_editable = ['manual']
```

How can I use search_fields for integer value??

Answer (score 0):

You can use `search_fields` for an integer value(try searching the int value in the search box) but Django doesn't provide a pull-down menu for search. You can, however, use a [`list_filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) to achieve a similar result.

```
class CorpusAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['text','manual']
    search_fields = ['text','manual']
    list_editable = ['manual']  
    list_filter = ['manual', ]
```